# Sanitise the names of uploaded files

Tags: php, regex, file-upload

I am trying to sanitise the file names of files uploaded.

I want to replace everything that isn't a number or letter, and replace spaces with -

I have:

```
$finalName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9][ ]/', '-', strtolower(substr($finalName, 0, strpos($finalName, '.')))) ;
```

Which doesn't work.

Could someone help me out with my regular expression?

Note that:

```
substr($finalName, 0, strpos($finalName, '.'))
```

Is just so it works on the file name and not the dot or extension.

Comment: Don't sanitize uploaded file names, make your own!  What happens when someone uploads files of conflicting names?  What happens when someone gets around your sanitization?  Your file names should be based on something sequential.

Comment: @Brad Excellent point, I have decided to take your advise and have the user enter an seo friendly image name e.g. descriptive-image-name, which will then be validated.

Comment: What I do instead:  Never store user files in the doc root.  Never allow users to specify a file name.  Keep the file information in a database, and then on request, return the file data.  Basically, you make a safe and transparent storage mechanism this way.  Also, never trust the users' content types.

Comment: ... and never feed them after midnight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use **or** within the regex

```
/[^a-z0-9]+|[ ]+/
           ^
```